# Why I can't open a website with the requested “.com” domain instead of the redirected country-specific domain?

Tags: dns, internet, website, domain

Every time I try to open one website I get redirected to the website but with local domain (domain of the country I am in).

The website in the local domain is written in the local language. That’s why I want to open it in `.com`, but every time I get redirected.

1. So why is this happening? Is it cause of DNS?
2. Does this depends on the ISP that I am using? Maybe with other ISP is different?
3. What are the options that I can use to open the site in `.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, how it is done is site-specific. However, there are a few basic ways a website might try to detect your country and language:

- The HTTP [`Accept-Language`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5) header, as sent by your browser. This is the preferred method, and specifies the language *and* region you prefer (e.g. en-AU is different from en-GB and en-US). Most browsers let you change the languages you want in the settings. The W3C has published an [article](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php) with [instructions](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-priorities.en.php#changing) on changing this for some popular browsers.
- Your IP address geo-location. This is still used by some sites, but is generally considered a bad idea. Unfortunately there isn't much you can do apart from using a proxy or VPN to another country. You should contact the website operator and ask them to give you the option to choose.
- DNS can also be used to point users to a specific server (by IP), but I have not seen this done for domain/region redirection. Anycast routing can achieve a similar effect. Again, you're stuck with a proxy/VPN, or asking the website operator to make changes.